# Word VBA Macro -- Write multiple items to a txt file?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm working on a project to store what a user cuts/copies/pastes within a Word document, and am using the VBA macros to accomplish this. Here's a snippet from the paste macro:

```
Open "C:\Temp\HoldPastes.txt" For Output As #1
      Write #1, "TestTestTest."
      Write #1, Selection
      Close #1
```

I'd like HoldPastes.txt to have a list of every chunk of text the user has pasted.

First off, `Write #1, Selection` is wrong; it puts two quotation marks into my txt file. How can I access what's been pasted from the clipboard and write that to my file?

Also, this overwrites whatever I had in HoldPastes.txt. I'd like to preserve all pastes in this file, so how can I tell the macro to pick up where it left off and add to the file?

Answer (score 2):

Append to a file is not `For Output` but `For Append`

```
Open "C:\Temp\HoldPastes.txt" For Append As #1
```

Read the Clipboard

```
Dim myData As DataObject
Dim strClip As String

Set myData = New DataObject
myData.GetFromClipboard
strClip = myData.GetText
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

instead of:
     write #1, "text"
you need to use:
     print #1, "text"

the write command will always use " marks around the data being saved to the file.